# Is it natural to ask "Is it good" about a cafe?

Tags: idiomatic-language

A: I own a cafe downtown. You should try it out.

B: Yeah? **Is it good?**

Is asking "is it good?" natural here?

Answer (score 1):

"Good" can apply to a cafe. Good can be used to describe most things..

What is odd here is asking *the owner*, who has just recommended the cafe to you if it is good.  Do you think it likely that they will say "No, my cafe is a bad cafe. I want you to try it out because nobody else ever goes there!"?

Of course not.  So the question is a bit pointless...  of course lots of conversation is pointless, but there are lots of better questions you could ask:

> Where is it?
>
> How big is it?
>
> Do you serve pastries?